# java4 installation detects java8

Tags: java, legacy, system-variable

I'm preparing a VM with Windows XP, Java 4 and Java 8 for university projects purposes.

Before installing Java4 I first installed 7 and 8 for gradle, intellij and some other projects.

After all the installation stuff, i set my JAVA_HOME variable to

```
C:\Developer\SDK\Java\j2sdk1.4.2_19
```

and added JAVA_HOME\bin to the PATH variable.

It should all work fine, but when I opened CMD and issued

```
java -version
```

java 8 version is printed. On the other hand, javac -version prints nothing but the help dialog.

Am I doing anything wrong?

**Images**

[image]

[image]

Comment: It needs to be `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`. It also might need to be first in the list in your path.

Comment: ok, I had it in the format you said (I do know the syntax, have worked with variables a lot), but placing it first solved it somehow, thank you very much.

Comment: Next time you can try using the `where` command to know which java executable you are actually running (`whereis` on *nix envmts)

Comment: I did know where they were actually and somehow `where` isn't working on my VM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sev said, placing it first in the path variable solved the issue